# How I can calculate the MD5 in PHP of the all values of array

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

How I can calculate the MD5 in PHP of the all values of array below:

```
array(2) {
    ["cabecalho"]=> array(5) {
        ["identificacaoTransacao"]=> array(4) { 
            ["tipoTransacao"]=> string(22) "VERIFICA_ELEGIBILIDADE"
            ["sequencialTransacao"]=> int(1)
            ["dataRegistroTransacao"]=> string(10) "2014-05-22
            ["horaRegistroTransacao"]=> string(8) "17:00:00"
        }
        ["origem"]=> array(1) {
            ["codigoPrestadorNaOperadora"]=> array(1) {
                ["CNPJ"]=> string(14) "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
            }
        }
        ["destino"]=> array(1) {
            ["codigoPrestadorNaOperadora"]=> array(1) {
                ["CNPJ"]=> string(14) "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
            }
        }
        ["versaoPadrao"]=> string(7) "2.02.03" 
        ["identificacaoSoftwareGerador"]=> array(3) {
            ["nomeAplicativo"]=> string(10) "XXXXXXXXXX"
            ["versaoAplicativo"]=> string(6) "V1.0.0"
            ["fabricanteAplicativo"]=> string(27) "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        }
    }
    ["verificaElegibilidade"]=> array(2) {
        ["dadosPrestador"]=> array(2) {
            ["identificacao"]=> array(1) {
                ["codigoPrestadorNaOperadora"]=> string(8) "XXXXXXXXX"
            } 
            ["nomeContratado"]=> string(26) "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        }
        ["dadosBeneficiario"]=> array(3) {
            ["numeroCarteira"]=> string(9) "XXXXXXXXXX"
            ["nomeBeneficiario"]=> string(22) "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
            ["nomePlano"]=> string(24) "MEDIAL 300 RM OR QC PJCE" 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The purpose of your question's title is to inform us about the problem -- not the subjective gravity you feel for it or the perceived usefulness regarding it.

Comment: Serialize entire array before calculate MD5.

Comment: What is the purpose of this MD5? What if you have another array with the same elements, but in a different order? Should the array stay the same? And what if the array contains other arrays, should they also be evaluated ?

Comment: `$hash = md5(serialize($arr));`

Comment: Do you mean to create the hash of each individual value, leaving you with many hashes, or to hash the complete array as a whole?

Comment: @76200 I came here to post that as an answer, you should do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($hash);
...

```
    $mensagemTISS = '';
    $output = array();
    $els = $objDom->getElementsByTagName('*');
    for($i=0;$i<$els->length;$i++) {
            if(! $els->item($i)->hasChildNodes() ) {
            } elseif ($els->item($i)->firstChild->nodeType == 3 ) {
                    $tmp = $els->item($i)->textContent;
                    if ( preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $tmp) ) {
                            $tmp = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $tmp);("\n", "", $tmp);
                    }
                    $mensagemTISS = $mensagemTISS . ($tmp);
            }
    }
    echo '<hr>HASH: <pre>'.$mensagemTISS.'</pre><hr>';
    return md5($mensagemTISS);
```

Answer (score 1):

To calculate MD5 hash of multidimensional array do this: `$hash = md5(serialize($arr));`

Answer (score 0):

I would simply go with:

```
$hash = md5(serialize($array));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a combination of the functions `md5()`, `serialize()`. And also `array_multisort()` so arrays with the same keys and values, but with a different order will give the same hash.

```
$hash = md5(serialize(array_multisort($sorted_array)));
```